# Using "clone partition" of DiskGenius to transfer data from HDD to SSD copies nothing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, data-transfer

My laptop (Acer Nitro 5) had a broken HDD. So I bought a Samsung SSD (with SATA). I inserted the SSD to my laptop and installed windows-11.

Then I took the SSD out of the laptop and connected it with another computer(windows-7) where my data were backed up. I used "clone partition" of DiskGenius to transfer data from the HDD of the win-7 computer to my SSD.

However, when I insert the SSD into the laptop and turned on the laptop, nothing shows up as if data transfer were never done. But the strange thing is that when I connect the SSD back to the win-7 computer, I can find all the copied data.

(All the concerned partitions use NTFS as file system)

Why???

Can anyone help me?

---

Edit: The same phenomena appeared again when I switched to the AOMEI software to do the same thing.

Now I transferred my data from the win-7 computer to an extra HHD (via AOMEI's clone-partition). And I can see the copied data when the extra HHD is connected to either the win-7 computer or my laptop.

---

Edit again:

Now I finished the data transfer.

I first transfer the data from the win-7 HDD to a portable HDD. Then I connected the portable HDD to my laptop. Lastly I transferred the data from the portable HDD to the SSD of my laptop. All operations were done with AOMEI.

But I still don't know the reason why my problem stated above occurred.

Comment: Have you checked Disk Management? You might need to assign a drive letter to the partition you copied.

Comment: @LayneBernardo Yes I have. That partition is blank as was shown inside my laptop.

Comment: You can consider using third-party software EaseUS Partition Master https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/clone-larger-hdd-to-smaller-ssd.html which can copy data from a source partition to a target partition. You may use it to clone the NTFS drive, FAT32 drive, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with broken storage you never use fair weather software, such as DiskGenius.
Broken drives often come with so-called pending sectors (unreadable ones).
Most of the software around that deals with drives, volumes, partitions and files has not been programmed to deal with unreadable sectors.

Therefore you are better of using a fault-tolerant software such as ddrescue (Linux,open source, free) to create a copy that is at least physically healthy. That means that every sector can be read. Keep in mind that such a copy won't provide you with the content of pending sectors.
But having such a physically healthy disk ready, fair weather software can be used again.
ddrescue provides you with information about unreadable sectors and is updating this information during the copy process.

But the first thing to do which does not take time at all is to run a smartmontools test.

**smartctl -a /dev/sdX > mylogfile.txt**

Replace X by the letter that the drive is associated with.

You find a detailed description here:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910

Not every drive dammage is reflected in the SMART parameters but SMART provides you with lots of information.

Copying the drive is the second step after getting the SMART parameters.

Comment: Thanks. But after backing up the data, there is no broken storage concerned. That is to say, my problem occurred when I was trying to transfer data from a healthy HDD to a healthy SSD.